# Indent Error with my battleship.py script

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a simple two player game like the classic Battleship. Hence I'm beginning to learn Python and I'm keeping it simple. I have created a 5x5 grid and I want the players (2) to be able to place one ship 1x1 anywhere on the board. Then they take turns guessing where the other person placed their ship.

When I compiled my code I got an indent error on line 61 `"else: "`. I'm aware that the "H" and "M" for hit and miss will overlap since I'm outputting it to the same playing board.

I guess what I need help with is the while loops in my code.

```
import sys

#////////////////////////////Setting up board////////////////////////////////////
board = []

for x in range(5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print " ".join(row)


#///////////////////////////Getting input//////////////////////////////////////////
def user_row():
    get_row = raw_input("Enter ship row between 1 and 5")
    #Not shure if this is the best way of checking that the input is an int
    if int(get_row) == False:
        print "You must enter an integer between 1 and 5"
        get_row = raw_input("Enter ship row...")
        if int(get_row) == False:
            sys.exit()

def user_col():
    get_col = raw_input("Enter ship col between 1 and 5")
    if int(get_col) == False:
        print "You must enter an integer between 1 and 5"
        get_col = raw_input("Enter ship col...")
        if int(get_col) == False:
            sys.exit()

#/////////////////////////Intro//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
print "Let's play Battleship!"
print "This is your ocean"
print_board(board)


#////////////////////////Placing ships//////////////////////////////////////////////
print "Player 1 your up!"
print "Player 2 look away!"
print "Place your ship..."

#Not shure if this will call the two functions chronologic and store them as index 0 and 1 in my array. That is what I want it to do
user1_ship = [user_row(), user_col()]

print_board(board)
print "Player 2 your up!"
print "Player 1 look away!"
print "Place your ship..."

user_2 = [user_row(), user_col()]


#///////////////////////guesswork?//////////////////////////////////////////////////
#Maybe while loops inside while loops is not the best way of running the code over and over until someone sinks the other persons ship
#What Im expecting is the first inside while loop to break the outer loop if the player hits the other players ship otherwise break itself. Likewise with the second inner loop.
while True:
    while True:
        print "Player 1 your turn"
        user1_guess = [user_row(), user_col()]
        if user1_guess == user2_ship:
            board[user1_guess[0]][user1_guess[1]] == "H"
            print "PLAYER 1 WINS!"
    break
        else:
            board[user1_guess[0]][user1_guess[1]] == "M"
            print "You missed"
            break
    while True:
        print "Player 2 your turn"
        user2_guess = [user_row(), user_col()]
        if user2_guess == user1_ship:
            board[user2_guess[0]][user2_guess[1]] == "H"
            print "PLAYER 2 WINS!"
    break
        else:
            board[user2_guess[0]][user2_guess[1]] == "M"
            print "You missed"
            break
```

Comment: Exactly as the error said, you indentation is wrong. The `break` preceding the `else` cannot be at the indentation level you have it. Is that to try to break out of the outer `while` loop?

Comment: You might get some more of the help you want at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). It's another site in the network for people looking to improve their code and get more experienced coders' feedback on it.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan as long as the code has errors, it is off-topic for CR.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I meant to suggest it as where to get more feedback when it's working, since the asker just generally wants help with the script.

Comment: Just a tip for the future, many times when the interpreter says you have an indentation error or invalid syntax on line X the error is actually on the line above.

Answer (score 3):

Your indentation is incorrect... Look at this:

```
while True:
    while True:
        print "Player 1 your turn"
        user1_guess = [user_row(), user_col()]
        if user1_guess == user2_ship:
            board[user1_guess[0]][user1_guess[1]] == "H"
            print "PLAYER 1 WINS!"
    break
```

The `break` statement must have the same indentation as the `print` statement like this:

```
while True:
    while True:
        print "Player 1 your turn"
        user1_guess = [user_row(), user_col()]
        if user1_guess == user2_ship:
            board[user1_guess[0]][user1_guess[1]] == "H"
            print "PLAYER 1 WINS!"
            break
```

If you have some time, please read a [Python Styleguide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to improve the quality of your code.

Comment: I thought it was possible to break the whole outer while loop if the if-statement was met. Is this possible?

Comment: You must define a break statement in every loop. Otherwise, you can raise an [Exception()](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) and "Catch" it in the outer loop